# Can I get a driving license on a visitor visa?

Tags: driving, driving-licenses, new-zealand

I currently have a [visitor visa](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/about-visa/visitor-visa/) for 8 months. I have never gotten a license in my own country as I never needed it, but in NZ it's a bit tricky to get around without one, so I'm considering studying/applying for one.

I'm not sure if this is possible on a visitor visa though. The [NZTA website](https://www.nzta.govt.nz/driver-licences/) doesn't seem to mention much about this.

I am from the Netherlands.

Comment: I can't seem to find any obvious information about this either - if you had a current overseas license, it looks like it would be much easier. I would call NZTA on their 0800 number, they should be able to give you a straight answer.

Comment: Actually, I know somebody who was here in NZ on a long visitor visa, and they were able to swap their overseas license for a NZ license with no problem. So it's certainly *possible* for a visitor to hold an NZ license.

Comment: New Zealand has a graduated driver licence system; the first step, a learner's licence, doesn't allow you to drive without adequate supervision, and must be held for 6 months, before being able to sit the test for the next licence (which itself has some restrictions). So, assuming you are allowed to get a learner's licence, it might not actually be very useful for you.

Comment: Yeah, I read about that @walter, but for me the waiting period is only 3 months if I do a defensive driving course (as I'm over 30), so while not optimal, it's probably better than not getting a license (even a provisional one would be useful, so my girlfriend won't have to do 100% of the driving). Either way, I'd like to know what my options are.

Comment: As I read it @MartinTournoij, the waiting period learner - restricted is always 6 months, and for a someone over 25 with a defensive driving course, the period restricted - full is 3 months.

Comment: Yes, you're correct @walter, but the restricted license is already very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted the NZ Transport Agency to ask them if there was any residency requirement for obtaining a driver license. They said anyone can apply for a license while visiting New Zealand.

> If they are wanting to apply through the New Zealand Driver Licence
>   system and are not going to be converting an overseas licence the
>   following applies:
>
> - Provide ID such as Overseas Passport and a supporting ID (Bank statement, Utility Bill, IRD letter with IRD number, overseas licence)
> - Complete the DL1 application form through AA or VTNZ
> - Sit and pass the Learner licence theory test
> - Once the licence has been obtained the licence holder will need to remain on that licence for a minimum of 6 months
> - Once 6 months has elapsed the licence holder is able to apply for the New Zealand Restricted licence
> - Sit and pass the Restricted licence practical driving test

I suppose in theory you even obtain a license in multiple visits if you desired, although this would be an expensive exercise.